# Is there a way to recieve HTML canvas data?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas (for example, a map). Now i want to get an object from the canvas(e.g: get its color, get the text inside the object). I know that I can get pixels from canvas, but i wanted to know if there is a way to get canvas info in other way(JavaScript, or external libraries).

Comment: What do you mean an “object”?

Comment: Eventually there are no “objects” on your canvas, there are only pixels. You would have to intervene at whatever points the script/library creating your canvas content is actually dealing with any such objects.